# SQL change database dynamically and create view

Tags: sql, exec, create-view

I need to create a view in another database.

I have some code like this:

```
--sql start

USE MyDB1
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].My_procedure
    DECLARE @prm_Name VARCHAR(60)
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @sql = ''

    SET @sql = concat('USE MyDB2
    GO

    CREATE VIEW [dbo].[',@prm_Name,'_view]
    AS
        SELECT * 
        FROM [dbo].', @prm_Name)

    EXECUTE(@sql)
END
--sql end
```

But I have syntax error near 'GO' when call this procedure.
I test :

```
  set @sql = concat('
    CREATE VIEW [MyDB2].[dbo].[',@prm_Name,'_view]
    AS
    SELECT * FROM [dbo].',@prm_Name)
  execute(@sql
```

But I have this error :"'CREATE/ALTER VIEW' does not allow specifying the database name as a prefix to the object name."

How can I create my view correctly?

Comment: Try to break the first attempt into two different sql execute and share the error.

Comment: I try and have this error - "Invalid object name 'dbo.TestTable'."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used "execute('execute....". And it's work))

Final code:

```
SET @sql = concat('
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[',@prm_Name,'_view]
AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM [dbo].', @prm_Name)
SET @sql = concat('
    USE MyDB2;
    execute(''',@sql,''')')

EXECUTE(@sql)
```